Find all data from collection first by one query following with rest of data by second query
I'm very new in mongo and I'm trying get all data from collection with two queries
I have items and every item has startDate.
I need get all data, first all items where startDate is lower then current Date sort by DESC and follow rest of data where startDate is greater then or equal to current date sort by ASC.
I don't know how could be done.
Sorry about my English, I'm new in that to.
I had tried do that on the next way
Long itemsNumber = mongoTemplate.count(
            Query.query(
                new Criteria().andOperator(finalCriteria, Criteria.where("type").in(ItemType.EVENT.name()).and("startDate").lt(new Date()))
            ), EventItem.class);
            
items = mongoTemplate.find(
        Query.query(
            new Criteria().andOperator(finalCriteria, Criteria.where("type").in(ItemType.EVENT.name()).and("startDate").lt(new Date()))
        )
        .limit(model.getPaging().getItemsPerPage())
        .skip(model.getPaging().getPage() * model.getPaging().getItemsPerPage())
        .with(Sort.by(Direction.DESC, "startDate")),
        EventItem.class
    );
    
if(items.size() < model.getPaging().getItemsPerPage()) {
        items.addAll(
            mongoTemplate.find(
                Query.query(
                    new Criteria().andOperator(finalCriteria, Criteria.where("type").in(ItemType.EVENT.name()).and("startDate").gte(new Date()))
                )
                .limit((int) (model.getPaging().getItemsPerPage() - items.size()))
                .skip(model.getPaging().getPage() * model.getPaging().getItemsPerPage() - itemsNumber)
                .with(Sort.by(Direction.ASC, "startDate")), 
                EventItem.class
            )
        );      
    }

But I would like do that trough one query if is possible

You need all items from a database.
List<Item> items = repository.findAll(...);
List<Item> firstGroup = items.stream().filter(item -> item.getStartDate().isBefore(current)).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Item> secondGroup = items.stream().filter(Predicate.not(item -> item.getStartDate().isBefore(current))).collect(Collectors.toList());

Forward data to next stage.

Thanks Akif. I've edited my question becouse I've tried do that on similar way I think. Is it possible do that in one query? But it seems that your way is faster
